# EF Core two foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I want to set SetNull delete behaviour for my db. I have two entities, `Contract` and `Status`, with relations:

Contract:

```
 public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
}
```

Status:

```
public class Status 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

I set in DBContext something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
            .HasOne(a => a.Status)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.StatusId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

But for some reason in the `Contract` table I have now a `StatusId` column and a `StatusId1` column... Has anyone idea what I did wrong? Thx!

Comment: The reason is `.WithMany()`, It has to be `.WithMany(s => s.Contracts)`

Comment: thanks, that solved my prob!